# Warning: rename(k.jpg,) [function.rename]: No error in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\uploader.php on line 15

Tags: php

> Warning: rename(k.jpg,) [function.rename]: No error in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\uploader.php on line 15

I keep getting this error, even though the file keeps getting moved into the correct folder...

```
$target_path = "schlImage/";
$school_name= $_SESSION["school_username"];
$nm=$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
        " has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

rename($nm,$school_name);
```

Comment: What do `$nm` and `$school_name` contain?

Comment: It's not error, it's a warning. An it can be suppressed: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php.

Comment: You don't have the path assigned in your `rename` variables. Does it get renamed as you expect it to?

Answer (score 0):

```
rename($nm,$school_name);
```

change to

```
$co = substr_count($nm,'.');
$ex = explode('.',$nm);
rename($target_path,"schlImage/".$school_name.".".$ex[$co]);
```

[See rename php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)